# How to parse data from a text file which contains lots of records and each value is separated by a space/tab or maybe both

Tags: java, parsing, file-handling

I actually need to create a database with 421 columns and I have created it. Now I have to load data into the database using a Java program. The data that I need to input into the DB is present in a text file. The values in the text file are separated by space/tab or may be both. How do I extract data from this text file so that the first value is entered under column1, second value under column 2 and so on.... 421st value under column421 and 422nd value under 1st column again and so on. I am little poor at file handling and parsing in java, so please help.

Comment: You really want to use the search box here on SO, as you will find plenty of information on how to 1) read the contents of a text file and 2) parse a delimited file.

Comment: Having 421 columns? I think you need to recheck your database design. Are you sure it conforms to at least 1st, 2nd, and 3rd normal forms?

Comment: The columns are nothing but test data. So, there are no keys involved. I need all 421 columns because, they are used by a reporting tool named cognos.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont do with sql statement? Below example for mysql, I showed delimiter as tab:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.csv'
INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1, filed2, field3);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

edit:

if delimiter is optional maybe you can read via buffered reader an analyze? I didnt check the code but you can write something like this and check text during the loop. I have replaced all tabs to space then I used delimiter as space but if your values containing space then it is problem

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myText.txt"));

String s;

while((s=br.ReadLine)!= null){
   s.replace("\t"," ");
   String[] sub = s.split(" ");
   String statement = "insert into myTable (clm1, clm2, clm3) Values (";

   for(int i=0:i<sub.length;i++){
       if((i % 420) == 0){
         mySqlStatement.ExecuteQuery(statement);
         statement = "insert into myTable (clm1, clm2, clm3) Values (";
       }
       if(i==0){
          statement = statement + sub(i);
       }else{
          statement = statement + "," + sub(i);
       }
   }
   statement = statement + ")";
  mySqlStatement.ExecuteQuery(statement);
}
```

Comment: the lines are not terminated. Its a text file containing many values(separated by space/tab).Also, I need to do it using a Java program only with File handling and parsing. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it helps understanding how to proceed atleast. But one thing here i see is, you are only considering the case with tabs(\t).

Comment: yes I have replaced all tabs with space you can do also with opposite way. This is not the business standard or maybe not the best way but it should work. OR: you can scan all text char to char and handle condition if there is space or tab.

Answer (score 0):

421 columns? Wow, you probably should split that huge table into a proper model with relationship. But anyway, that's off-topic.
If you really want to do it using Java, here is a possibility:

```
public static void readFromFile(String pathToFile) {
    final BufferedReader reader = getFileReaderInClasspath(pathToFile);
    try {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\s\t");
            final List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                columns.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
            saveIntoDb(columns);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error reading file (" + pathToFile + ")", e);
    }
}
```

And obviously you'll need to implement the `saveIntoDb(List)` method, that inserts the columns into your database.
Alternatively, you could store each list of columns into a

```
List<List<String>>
```

which contains all the rows, and add all of that to the database at the end of the process only.